# Does new Google Music Beta support end user selection of songs via intents

Tags: android, google-music

I have an application that uses `ACTION_PICK` to allow the user to pick a song.  Once that song is picked, the application uses the cursor location and does another intent later on to show the `NOW_PLAYING` interface.  The application worked fine until I installed Music Beta on my droid device.  The application then began failing with `UnsupportedOperationException`.  The intent and filters looked like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/track");
this.startActivity(intent);
```

I uninstalled Music Bata and the application again worked fine.  Wanted to see if this was a bug related to new Google music application and see if anyone else was having this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [MusicUtils.java](http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/music/MusicUtils.java.html). In there there are some calls to pick a song. They all have:

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.EMPTY, "vnd.android.cursor.dir/track");
```

On [another place](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/donut/packages/apps/Music/src/com/android/music/PlaylistBrowserActivity.java) I found:

```
if (id == RECENTLY_ADDED_PLAYLIST) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.EMPTY, "vnd.android.cursor.dir/track");
    intent.putExtra("playlist", "recentlyadded");
    startActivity(intent);
} else if (id == PODCASTS_PLAYLIST) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.EMPTY, "vnd.android.cursor.dir/track");
    intent.putExtra("playlist", "podcasts");
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.EMPTY, "vnd.android.cursor.dir/track");
    intent.putExtra("playlist", Long.valueOf(id).toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In both files the Intent is routed with Uri.EMPTY

Comment: Thanks Kamen.  I changed my code using the empty Uri, reinstalled music bata and tested the app.  It failed with same error code:     05-27 08:44:19.882: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17762): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 08:44:19.882: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17762): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat= typ=vnd.android.cursor.dir/track }
05-27 08:44:19.882: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17762):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)

Comment: What's the log for the exception?

Comment: That was a portion of the log, I can't post the entire log here for some reason...not enough character space....05-27 08:44:19.882: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17762): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 08:44:19.882: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17762): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat= typ=vnd.android.cursor.dir/track }
05-27 08:44:19.882: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17762):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)

Comment: Doesn't seem good :) It really seems to be something causes by Music Beta. You'd better try to contact the Music team. Sorry...